# Hello I am making an endless death race game where I have to generate endless patches. Can I use unity terrain as an endless patch?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have tried to pool unity terrain but its cost is very high for a mobile game . I want to keep it optimised.Is using an fix file as a patch is more good or terrain can be used for this purpose ?

Answer (score 0):

Using unity terrain in mobile is very costly, You can use terrain in mobile but only after extensive optimization like limiting textures used on terrain etc(Just google, you will find tons of optimization tricks).
Back to your question, I am not really sure how you are generating endless terrain but the best way is move terrain with the player position to give the sense of endless world and pool game object as required.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure why do you specifically need to use the standard terrain but you can consider using other terrain assets or make a terrain in other softwares. You can easily make one in Blender but there are lots of more alternatives.